# mPDF font-size not working for long text in a table

Tags: font-size, mpdf

Using mPDF to print html to pdf the font-size I set in html is not properly set in creating the pdf. 
In my html I have

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:myriadpro, Verdana, sans-serif; color:#111111;">
<tr>
<td align="left" style="vertical-align:top; padding:5px; font-size: 12pt;">
etc.
```

However mPDF scales the font-size to 9pt in the PDF. If I use 24pt it scales to 18pt. I checked and tried to change the configs and displaypreferences (NoPrintScaling) in mPDF but none of this is working.

Has anybody got a clue on how to get rid of this scaling? I don´t want to set the font-size bigger to compensate for mPDF behaviour because that will ruin my html view.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

mPDF uses autosizing tables and this influences, among other things, the font-size as well. When outputting tables with mPDF you need to set:

```
<table style="overflow: wrap">
```

on every table. See Auto-layout algorithm in the [mPDF manual](https://mpdf.github.io/tables/auto-layout-algorithm.html) for reference.

Comment: That link does not exists now

Comment: @Yo Yo. The original mPDF manual apparantly is not online anymore but a copy is made available on github. I have changed the link accordingly.

Comment: @zef Link links to the manual but it does not work with 'wrap' for me, but with 'hidden' it does. Thanks

Comment: And, I forgot, it didn't work as a style defined directly in tab html element, but it worked since I add 'overflow:hidden' to default styles to a table style generated in Html() class which is Mpdf class inherits from. I guess that same procedure is for external style file ...

Answer (score 4):

If anyone still got the same issue after tested with accepted answer, try this :

```
<table style="overflow: wrap" autosize="1">
```

And

```
$mPdf->shrink_tables_to_fit = 1;
```

Hope this helped as my case was solved only with these combination

Answer (score 0):

overflow: wrap and autosize="1" is not working for me , I also tried to replace the shrink_tables_to_fit => 1 in config.php(ConfigVariables.php)
I followed the div style and it worked , however I do have a problem with the borders when the content is too long